# HTML input field does not save Text when pressing submit button?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I'm kind of stuck how to validate this form properly. Actually, its kind of working, but when ever I type in something right/wrong, then press submit button, the text does not remain saved in the input fields, it makes me to type everything again.
 I'm a noob in php & some great folks here had helped me to validate form in PHP. 
Also, I want to know, is it possible to use both JS & php to validate the form together? 
I'm using validate plugin on client side & php on server if user has js disabled.
If you don't mind plz check out the form if its ok..
btw plz disable js to see the problem when php checks the form.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vka7cy70xv4zryf/formtest.zip
Thank you for ur time!

```
<title>FormTest</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"/>

        <style type="text/css">
            .formerrors li{color:yellow;
                font-size:14px;
                font-weight:lighter;
                font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;}


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="contact">
    <h1 class="heading1"> Contact:</h1>
        <form name="contact" action="" method="post">

            <label for="YourName">Your Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="required" />

            <label for="YourEmail">Your Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="required"/>

            <label for="Subject">Subject:</label>
            <input type="text" name="subject" class="required"  />

            <label for="YourMessage">Your Message:</label>
            <textarea  name="message" class="required"></textarea>
            <p class="c3">10 + 5 =<input type="text" name="answerbox" id="answerbox" /></p>

        <fieldset>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" class="required"/>
            <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset"/>      
        </fieldset>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $subject = trim($_POST["subject"]);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);
    $answerbox = trim($_POST["answerbox"]);
    if(empty($_POST['name'])){
        echo "<div class='formerrors'><li>Please type your name.</li></div>";
    } else {
        if (ctype_alpha($name) === false) {
        echo "<div class='formerrors'><li>Your name only contain letters!</li></div>";
        }
    }


    if(empty($_POST['email'])){
        echo "<div class='formerrors'><li>You've forgot to type your email address.</li></div>";
    } else{
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
            echo "<div class='formerrors'><li>Your email is not valid, please check.</li></div>";
        }
    }
    if(empty($_POST['subject'])){
        echo "<div class='formerrors'><li>Please type a subject.</li></div>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['message'])){
        echo "<div class='formerrors'><li>You've forgot to type your message.</li></div>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['answerbox'])){
        echo "<div class='formerrors'><li>Please answer the math question.</li></div>";
    }   else
    if($answerbox != 15){
            echo "<div class='formerrors'><li>Answer is not correct.</li></div>";
    }
    else{
        $headers =  'From: '.$email. "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: '.$email . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        mail('me@mymail.me',$subject,$message,$headers);
        print "Your message was sent successfully";
    }
}


?>
    </form>
</div><!--contact-->

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) 
                            {return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
                        }, "Letters only please.");

                      $("form").validate({

                        rules:{
                            name: {required: true,
                                maxlength:30,
                                lettersonly: true,},


                            email: {required: true,
                                email: true,
                                minlength: 5,
                                maxlength:40},              

                        answerbox: {required: true,
                                max: 15,
                                min: 15},
                        },

                      });
                    });

</script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do not add potentially malicious zipped attachments here. Post the code right in the question.

Comment: Hi,
no its not malicious, doesn't contain any virus or anything like that, I just uploaded, for visual look only.
I will post code now

Comment: you could put: `<input value="<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>" />` so you can keep the data in the form after submit.

Comment: He said "potentially malicious" and what is the problem here ? submit is supposed to do that what is it that you want to achieve ?

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for ur help, it works now..but how to remove it from appearing in Textarea field & the answerbox input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the site reloads the form is cleared.

You have to fill it in by yourself.

If you have an input field like this:

```
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" />
```

You can do this:

```
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="<?= isset($_POST['test']) ? $_POST['test'] : '' ?>" />
```

Another example with already set value:

```
<input type="text" name="test2" id="test2" value="Hello" />
```

becomes:

```
<input type="text" name="test2" id="test2" value="<?= isset($_POST['test2']) ? $_POST['test2'] : 'Hello' ?>" />
```

This checks if the POST Fields are set (that happens when the form was submitted) and then sets the form fields, else where empty or a default value.

You can also epand this by additionally checking if the form was invalid and then fill the fields otherwise not.

Example for Text Areas:

```
<textarea name="testtxt" id="testtxt"></textarea>
```

becomes:

```
<textarea name="testtxt" id="testtxt"><?= isset($_POST['testtxt']) ? $_POST['testtxt'] : '' ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for ur help, it works now..but how to remove it from appearing in Textarea field & the answerbox input?

Comment: If you don't want to have a field set like the answer box, then change it back like it was before, without setting a value

Answer (score 0):

Name: input type="text" name="name" value= php echo $name;

keep value:--

value=?php echo $name;?